# Using a form with formsets in Django

Tags: python, validation, form, django

I'm learning Django and making my (technically second) project.

The project features several apps, including **player_interface** and **manager_interface**.

Here's the player_interface/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                limit_choices_to={'is_staff': False})
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'PlayerProfile user_id={self.user_id} balance={self.balance}'
```

In the manager_interface app, I want to create users together with corresponding player profiles. So I made a form (in manager_interface/forms.py):

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import transaction

from player_interface.models import PlayerProfile


PlayerProfileUserFormset = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    User, PlayerProfile, fields=('balance',),
    extra=1, max_num=1, can_delete=False)


class PlayerUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, instance=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(data=data, instance=instance, **kwargs)
        self.formset = PlayerProfileUserFormset(data=data,
                                                instance=self.instance)

    def is_valid(self):
        return super().is_valid and self.formset.is_valid()

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        super().save()
        self.formset.save()
        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

And this is how I use this form in manager_interface/views.py:

```
<...>

class CUPlayerMixin:
    template_name = 'manager_interface/players_form.html'
    form_class = PlayerUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('players_list')


class CreatePlayerView(CUPlayerMixin, edit_views.CreateView):
    pass


class UpdatePlayerView(CUPlayerMixin, edit_views.UpdateView):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=False)
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = slug_field
```

And the relevant template bit is:

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <div>{{ form.formset.as_p }}</div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The code above works.

My question is: *is this a good, Django way to handle a form for both a model and its association?*

In this case, I edit both the `User` model with the associated `PlayerProfile`. That's why I decided to use the formset: it would automatically populate the subform for the player profile and then save it with the `self.formset.save()` part, keeping track of the association and all.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The way I understand it, I can call `formset.save()` and it will automatically create the player profile with the user instance set, etc. If I understand this correctly, if I just make a simple form, I'll have to create the profile instance manually.

Comment: Yes (`PlayerUserForm` is, in fact, a `ModelForm`), but I would still have to create the `PlayerProfile` instance manually, would I not?

Comment: I just use `{{ form.as_p }}` and then `{{ form.formset.as_p }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right approach of creating two separate forms for your two models involved (`User` and `PlayerProfile`) but I think the formset is overkill and not the right tool for the job anyway.

I’d rather create the `ModelForm`s more naturally:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')


class PlayerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerProfile
        fields = ('balance',)
```

And glue them together with an ad-hoc "form" along the lines of:

```
class PlayerUserForm:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_form = UserForm(*args, **kwargs)
        self.player_form = PlayerProfileForm(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_valid(self):
        # Make sure to **not** short-circuit so as
        # to populate both forms errors, if any. 
        user_valid = self.user_form.is_valid()
        player_valid = self.player_form.is_valid()
        return user_valid and player_valid

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = self.user_form.save()
        player = self.player_form.save(commit=False)
        player.user = user
        player.save()
        return player
```

And you can add template helpers for good measure:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.as_table()

    def as_table(self):
        return mark_safe(f'{self.user_form.as_table()}\n{self.player_form.as_table()}')

    def as_ul(self):
        return mark_safe(f'{self.user_form.as_ul()}\n{self.player_form.as_ul()}')

    def as_p(self):
        return mark_safe(f'{self.user_form.as_p()}\n{self.player_form.as_p()}')
```

This is untested but should work as a drop-in replacement for your `PlayerUserForm`.